# Display Image and text with gridview or galary in 1 row and multiple column with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am working on a application which require image and text group together in horizontal scroll bar.
I have tried few things but i am unable to get this, can anyone guide me with this guys.

Here is what i a have done,

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <HorizontalScrollView 
   android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:scrollbars="horizontal" > 
    <GridView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/gridView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
    </GridView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

gridview_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="64dp" 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="64dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>


</RelativeLayout>

GridviewExampleActivity.java

package com.paresh.gridviewexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GridViewExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private GridviewAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;

    private GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        prepareList();

        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
        mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this,listCountry, listFlag);

        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Implement On Item click listener
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(GridViewExampleActivity.this, mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void prepareList()
    {
          listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();

          listCountry.add("india");
          listCountry.add("Brazil");
          listCountry.add("Canada");
          listCountry.add("China");
          listCountry.add("France");
          listCountry.add("Germany");
          listCountry.add("Iran");
          listCountry.add("Italy");
          listCountry.add("Japan");
          listCountry.add("Korea");
          listCountry.add("Mexico");  
          listCountry.add("Netherlands");
          listCountry.add("Portugal");  
          listCountry.add("Russia");
          listCountry.add("Saudi Arabia");  
          listCountry.add("Spain");
          listCountry.add("Turkey");
          listCountry.add("United Kingdom");
          listCountry.add("United States");

          listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.india);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.brazil);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.canada);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.china);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.france);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.germany);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.iran);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.italy);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.japan);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.korea);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.mexico);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.netherlands);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.portugal);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.russia);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.saudi_arabia);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.spain);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.turkey);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.united_kingdom);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.united_states);
    }

}


GridviewAdapter.java

package com.paresh.gridviewexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
    private Activity activity;

    public GridviewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> listCountry, ArrayList<Integer> listFlag) {
        super();
        this.listCountry = listCountry;
        this.listFlag = listFlag;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);

            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            convertView.setTag(view);
        }
        else
        {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
        view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

My ouput should be

```
------------       ----------              ------------     ----
Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image 

Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text 
------------       ----------              ------------         --
```

Please Help me guys

Comment: Have you considered using a ViewPager ?

Comment: I have considered viewpager but it doesnot fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there just have a look at CustomArrayAdapter used for ListViews and Gridviews especially point 10 at [this Tutoiral](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/gridview/android-gridview-example/) there you get to know how to customize your GridView/ListView (handled same way)

[This might also help](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/gridview/android-gridview-example/)

If you have problems with the hotrizontal way, try this project: https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Comment: -soma-web I have gone through your example , I require my output be be display in a single row, not in multiple rows.